# does gorm preload not work with collection of objects?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to fetch all the modules from db where `status != Complete`.

My module table has many to many mapping with section table and section table has many to many mapping with field table.

I am trying to fetch all the modules in single DB query with statement below.

```
dbConnection.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Where("status != ?", enum.Completed).Find(&modules)
```

But it does not return sections and fields.
If I use below statement then it does return nested models.

```
dbConnection.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Where("status != ?", enum.Completed).First(&modules)
```

Does it mean it only works on single record not on collection?

Comment: How did you set up the model structs? It works for me when I use the `Preload()` function though. For example in your case: `db.Preload("Sections").Preload("Sections.Fields").Where("status != ?", enum.Completed).Find(&modules)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dbConnection.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true)`, you can load child relation only but if you want to load child of child also then you have to use nested preloading. Like

```
db.Preload("Sections").Preload("Sections.Fields").Find(&modules)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code based on you description, you can find the full code at the bottom. Lets go through different options:

```
// Use auto_preload and .First
db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Where("name = ?", "m0").First(&modules)

Output:
[{ID:1 Name:m0 Status:0 Sections:[{ID:2 Name:s1 Fields:[]}]}]
```

So with `.First` you get the sections but not the `Sections.Fields`

```
// Use auto_preload and .Find
db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Find(&modules)

Output:
[{ID:1 Name:m0 Status:0 Sections:[{ID:2 Name:s1 Fields:[]}]} {ID:2 Name:m1 Status:0 Sections:[{ID:1 Name:s0 Fields:[]}]}]
```

With `.Find` you get the same behaviour of `.First`

```
// Use .Preload
db.Preload("Sections").Preload("Sections.Fields").Find(&modules)

Output:
[{ID:1 Name:m0 Status:0 Sections:[{ID:2 Name:s1 Fields:[{ID:1 Name:f0} {ID:2 Name:f1}]}]} {ID:2 Name:m1 Status:0 Sections:[{ID:1 Name:s0 Fields:[{ID:1 Name:f0} {ID:3 Name:f2}]}]}]
```

With explicit preloading you can load both `Sections` and `Sections.Fields`. Using `auto_preload` only preload the immediate fields, not deeper fields. IMO using explicit preloading is a better practice generally.

Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
    "log"
)

type Module struct {
    ID       int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name     string
    Status   int
    Sections []Section `gorm:"many2many:module_sections;"`
}

type Section struct {
    ID     int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name   string
    Fields []Field `gorm:"many2many:section_fields;"`
}

type Field struct {
    ID   int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name string
}

func preloadingSample() error {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("open DB failed: %w", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.AutoMigrate(
        &Module{},
        &Section{},
        &Field{},
    ).Error
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("migration failed: %w", err)
    }

    // Delete everything in DB
    db.Delete(&Module{})
    db.Delete(&Section{})
    db.Delete(&Field{})

    // Put some sample data in DB
    sampleFields := []Field{
        {Name: "f0"},
        {Name: "f1"},
        {Name: "f2"},
        {Name: "f3"},
    }
    for idx := range sampleFields {
        err = db.Create(&sampleFields[idx]).Error
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to create: %w", err)
        }
    }

    sampleSections := []Section{
        {Name: "s0", Fields: []Field{sampleFields[0], sampleFields[2]}},
        {Name: "s1", Fields: []Field{sampleFields[0], sampleFields[1]}},
    }
    for idx := range sampleSections {
        err = db.Create(&sampleSections[idx]).Error
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to create: %w", err)
        }
    }

    sampleModules := []Module{
        {Name: "m0", Sections: []Section{sampleSections[1]}},
        {Name: "m1", Sections: []Section{sampleSections[0]}},
    }
    for idx := range sampleModules {
        err = db.Create(&sampleModules[idx]).Error
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to create: %w", err)
        }
    }

    var modules []Module

    // Load just one module with auto_preload
    err = db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Where("name = ?", "m0").First(&modules).Error
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("auto_preload first: %w", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", modules)

    // Load all modules with auto_preload
    err = db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Find(&modules).Error
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("auto_preload find: %w", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", modules)

    // Explicitly load
    err = db.Preload("Sections").Preload("Sections.Fields").Find(&modules).Error
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("preload find: %w", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", modules)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := preloadingSample()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```